# Displacement for rotation along some axis

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

If I rotate something along some axis which has direction $\vec \Omega$, at an small angle $\epsilon$ and if the position of the body is $\vec R$ then according to my book the displacement will be $$\delta R=\epsilon\vec\Omega\times\vec R$$
I am unable to understand how this happened. I will be helpful if someone illustrate it to me.

Comment: The first page of [this set of notes](https://www.astro.caltech.edu/~golwala/ph125ab/ph106ab_notes_sec5.1.pdf) provides a picture for why this formula should hold, and explains it briefly. Are you perhaps looking for a more analytical/algebraic approach as opposed to one which relies solely on pictures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The rotation direction is perpendicular to $\vec{\Omega}$ and $\vec{R}$ and is given by $\vec{v} = \frac{\vec{\Omega}\times\vec{R}}{||\vec{R}||}$. Note that $\vec{v}$ is a unit vector. The vector $\vec{R}$ rotates in this direction and thus $\vec{v} \parallel \delta R$.
2. If you draw a triangle with bases $\vec{R}$ and $\delta R$, you find $\tan(\epsilon) = \frac{||\delta R||}{||R||}$. This means that the amplitude of the displacement is given by $||\delta R||= \tan(\epsilon)||\vec{R}||$.
3. So, now we know the amplitude and direction of the displacement which gives
   $$\delta R = ||\delta R||\vec{v} = \tan(\epsilon)||\vec{R}||\frac{\vec{\Omega}\times\vec{R}}{||\vec{R}||} = \tan(\epsilon)(\vec{\Omega}\times\vec{R}) \,.$$
4. For small angles, the tangent can be approximated by $\tan(\epsilon) \approx \epsilon$ which gives the result
   $$\delta R =\epsilon(\vec{\Omega}\times\vec{R}) \,.$$

Answer (score 0):

I have this answer for you ?

from this equation:

$$\vec v=\vec \omega \times \vec R\quad\Rightarrow\quad\frac{d \vec R}{dt}=\frac {d \vec \varphi}{dt}\times \vec R$$

thus :

$$\delta \vec R=\delta \vec \varphi \times \vec R\tag 1$$

for equation (1)  equal to

$$\delta \vec R=\epsilon\vec\omega\times \vec R =\epsilon \frac {\delta \vec \varphi}{\delta t}\times \vec R\tag 2$$

$\epsilon$ must be equal to $\delta t$.  This doesn't make sense for me!